# ItemTouchHelper drag and drop groups

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two types of ViewHolders in a RecyclerView, one being group headers and the other one being group items. Is it possible to have the items move simultaneously with the group using ItemTouchHelper?

Or more generally, is it possible to have multiple viewholders move simultaneously when dragging one of them?

Comment: So you mean you have a expandable list with drag and swipe behavior via Itemtouchhelper?